# UNITY: Everything looks Low Resolution. Even SVG vectors

Tags: unity-game-engine, svg, resolution

I'm new to Unity so Hopefully this is an easy fix.

So everything looks super low res for me. I wish my images looked high res.

Even SVG looks low res even though they're vector nodes, I don't get that at all but I assume Unity doesn't play with svg yet? the black outline graphic is SVG, the rest are PNG with alpha.

Take a peek at my three different windows. Let me know your suggestions (remember I don't know anything so the easiest thing can been overlooked)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all: Never zoom into the GameView ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Scale" slider on top of the game view. Right now it is set to 2.8x. When you do that Unity just zooms in but it doesn't set the the resolution or actually change anything at all. It's like moving the screen really close to your face :D Nothing else besides that particulat window is affected by this setting. So my advice would be to always keep it at 1. Unless you want to see something specific at the screen of course